# Errors while deploying a EAR in WildFly 10.0.0 Final

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-10

I have Maven project. When deploying the EAR of that application in WildFly 10.0.0 Final, I am getting `ClassNotFoundException: hcmgmt.servlets.logoutservlet error`.

Below is the stack trace.

> 2016-08-03 20:36:25,507 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC
>   service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./NASApp/hcmgmt.UndertowDeploymentInfoService:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./NASApp/hcmgmt.UndertowDeploymentInfoService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hcmgmt.servlets.logoutservlet from
>   [Module "deployment.hcmgmt.ear.hcmgmt-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from
>   Service Module Loader]    at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:281)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Do you have an entry your `web.xml` for `hcmgmt.servlets.logoutservlet`?

Comment: Hi James..Yes I do have a entry in web.xml. There no issue in deploying the same EAR in JBoss 4.2 and JDK 1.5.

Comment: Then that servlet is missing and it needs to be removed from your configuration. Older versions probably just ignore invalid entries.

Comment: Thanks James..It's worked for me now.